# around filter: at least x meters away from anything

Tags: openstreetmap, query, overpass-api

With the around filter I can find things close to anything for example: way(around.golf_course:250)["natural"="beach"]; How can I form the opposite? I need things who are at least minimum x meters away from anything.

Comment: Take everything and remove what is not around, use osm_id's for making the join.

Comment: I think it's not what I mean, for example:

Comment: way(area.searchArea)[leisure=golf_course]->.golf_course;
  ( 
    way(around.golf_course:250)["natural"="beach"];
    node(around.golf_course:250)["natural"="beach"];

Comment: with that query I have all beaches up to 250 meters away of any golf course, but I would like to display the beaches who are at least minimum 250 meters away of any golf course

Comment: Well, your filter translates to "Whole world except this tiny area" and if it works it would give troubles with queries like "highway=". It seems that overpass does not support "NOT" in any of the queries https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#The_map_query so you must resolve the problem on the client side with JavaScript or something. Do around query with value that is big enough to cover your whole map, another one with value 250 meters, and hide from the bigger set features with id=id of the small dataset.

Comment: may the difference statement can help me...  actually I would like to display natural=beach but unfortunately bunkers of some golf courses are misstagged as natural=beach. Do you know a query that display natural=beach within golf_couses ?

Comment: Yes, difference looks good, so try it. If you know that there are tagging errors why don't you correct them?

Comment: @OrlandoLieberum: checking natural=beach within golf_courses only works is the gold_course has a name=* tag - in which case you can use an area query.